# Azure b2c MSAL stuck at " Login_In_Progress" error AngularJS SPA + .Net project

Tags: angularjs, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c

I recently inherited this very old web application built with legacy AngularJS and the middleware written in C#. I'm trying to use Azure B2c OAuth using MSAL JS library but for the life of me can't figure it out. I successfully integrated on another project built with NodeJS and Vanilla JS but the similar implementation does not work in AngularJS app.

**Error**

```
    at ClientAuthError.AuthError [as constructor] (AuthError.ts:26:9)
    at new ClientAuthError (ClientAuthError.ts:108:9)
    at Function.ClientAuthError.createLoginInProgressError (ClientAuthError.ts:164:16)
    at UserAgentApplication.acquireTokenInteractive (UserAgentApplication.ts:398:63)
    at UserAgentApplication.loginRedirect (UserAgentApplication.ts:324:14)
    at m.$scope.onLoginClick (bundle.js?v=2.2:35:24)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:16418:15), <anonymous>:4:156)
    at e (angular.js:28951:13)
    at m.$eval (angular.js:19393:16)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:19492:20)
XHRClient.ts:42          
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/<tenant_id>/b2c_1_signin/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration 404 (Not Found)
```

Here's the implementation

**authConfig.js**

```
    auth: {
        clientId: "client_id",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/B2C_1_sign",
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
    }
};


// Add here scopes for id token to be used at MS Identity Platform endpoints.
const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["User.ReadWrite"]
};
```

**login.js**

````
function authCallback(error, response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(error);
                if (myMsal.getAccount()) {
                    showWelcomeMessage(myMsal.getAccount());
                }
            }
myMsal.handleRedirectCallback(authCallback);

$scope.onLoginClick = function () {
   myMsal.loginRedirect(
       {
         scopes: ["User.ReadWrite"],
         authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/<tenant_id>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signin"
                    });
            } ```
````

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277852/how-do-you-authenticate-aad-b2c-using-msal

Comment: Thanks @OlegProudnikov. I changed the endpoint but still no luck! I even updated msal lib version from 1.2.1 to 1.4.16.

Comment: Please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-angular-spa-app