# What is the difference between domain user and guest user in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've just started to use Azure AD B2C and found that we could create both domain accounts ({tenant}.onmicrosoft.com) and local accounts (any email address), which are called as "guest user". What is the difference between the two? Is there any use case in which we should use domain accounts?

[Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UiZS.png)

Comment: Where do you notice this?  Any chance you can share a URL?

Comment: I noticed this on Azure Portal. It seems that "+New user" button creates domain accounts, and "+New guest user" creates local accounts. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UiZS.png

Comment: I found another question and now I understand that we should not use Users & Groups blade of AAD B2C to create accounts.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239075/how-do-you-add-a-user-with-a-local-name-in-azure-active-directory-b2c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any use case in which we should use domain accounts?

Yes, when you need to connect over PowerShell.  Please see this documentation about ['Configuring delete permissions for your application'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#configure-delete-permissions-for-your-application).

Note: there could be more scenarios, that is just one that I know of.