# Azure AD B2C Invitation email

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Does anybody know why when I invite users to my Azure AD B2C some of them see different web page after clicking on invitation email? For example, user will @gmail.com will be asked to created Microsoft account but layout of this page will be different if his email would end with @mvrht.net.

I've tried to search anything on web but didn't find anything. Is there some kind of "magic? algorithm that decides this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Azure AD B2C Users should NOT be created via the Users & Groups blade**.

This blade, while available from the Azure AD B2C Edit Settings blade, is meant at this time to be used to manage users for regular (corporate/enterprise) Azure AD. While it is technically possible to create/add users via this blade, you'll end up with undesired/unexpected behavior such as users being created with @tenantname.onmicrosoft.com or having them created as Guests via the Azure AD B2B Collaboration feature (which is what's happening with your @gmail users) that ultimately can't sign in to your Azure AD B2C integrated applications.

In the context of Azure AD B2C, **you should only use this blade to browse the users in the tenant, always in read only mode**.

To create Azure AD B2C users, you should either:

- **Have the users sign-up by themselves via the Sign-up or unified Sign-up/Sign-in policy**.
- **Programatically pre-create the users via the Graph API**. For this approach check out [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) which contains a CLI to create users and showcases the code behind it.

*Source: [How do you add a user with a local name in Azure Active Directory B2C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239075/how-do-you-add-a-user-with-a-local-name-in-azure-active-directory-b2c)*