# Azure AD b2c : Getting error while trying to run the custom invitation policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am working on custom invitation policy for user so that they can register with the inviation link. I have created the required Policies to make a custom policy.below is the list

- Base_Extensions.XML
- Base.XML
- Invitation.XML

I have followed [Azure AD B2C pre-populate a custom attribute in the SignUp policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380468/azure-ad-b2c-pre-populate-a-custom-attribute-in-the-signup-policy) to make a custom policy.

Actually this was the answer to my previous question [Azure Ad b2c : Add new member user with invitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040172/azure-ad-b2c-add-new-member-user-with-invitation).

All the above policies are uploaded successfully. but When I try to run the invitation policy. I get the error.

[image]

Please help me to resolve this. I am totally blind that how to resolve this.

Comment: Did you enable app insights to troubleshoot? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom

Answer (score 0):

The above error *can* be caused by a claim type, which is referenced as an output claim by a self-asserted technical profile, that doesn't have an input type:

e.g.:

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_MyCustomClaim">
  <DisplayName>My Custom Claim</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

The `<ClaimType />` element might be missing the `<UserInputType />` element.